# How can Fonts be installed/registered with install4j

Tags: fonts, registry, install4j

I want to install TTF fonts on the host computer (running Windows) during installation of a software I make. Installing fonts on windows means 2 things :

- Copy TTF files in c:\windows\fonts. That is easy to do.
- Register the fonts that is : update the Windows Registry for Windows to update its font list. **My question is : how can I do this with install4j ?**

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've done it "the hard way", but it works. Here's my code :

```
String fontRegKey;
if (Util.isWindows9X())
{ fontRegKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts"; }
else
{ fontRegKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts"; }
String [] fontFilesNames = new String[]
    {"braille_tbfr2007_b-2.ttf","BrailleTBFr2007INSHEAb_thermo.ttf","LouisLouis.ttf","LouisLouisThermo.ttf"};
String [] fontNames = new String[]
    {"Braille TBFr2007 INS HEA (TrueType)","Braille TBFr2007 INS HEA thermo (TrueType)",
    "LouisLouis Braille (TrueType)","LouisLouis Braille Thermo (TrueType)"};

for (int i=0 ; i<fontNames.length ; i++)
{
    boolean write = WinRegistry.setValue(RegistryRoot.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, fontRegKey,fontNames[i], fontFilesNames[i]);
}

if (Util.isAtLeastWindowsXP()) //security : delete system font cache
{
    File sd = WinFileSystem.getSystemDirectory();
    File f = new File (sd.getAbsoluteFile()+"\\FNTCACHE.dat") ;
    if (f.exists()) {f.delete();}
}
return true; //mandatory for the script
```

Three final things :

- This is script is a **Run Script Action** i put in the **Finish screen** of the installer.
- Be sure to run this script only in windows environment because your installer will crash under other systems.
- This seems to be **unnecessary for WinXP** but **indispensable for Win7** for the fonts to be accessible in the font list after installation.

Answer (score 1):

See [this blog post](http://blog.stevienova.com/2007/09/28/installing-fonts-programmatically-on-windows/) on on how to install a font programatically. You would execute the mentioned "fontinst.exe" executable with a "Run executable" action.

Comment: Thanks, there's also "registerfont.exe" which do the same. But both programs are old, and it's not sure it will work under win7 or Win8. I'll give it a try.